# Drag & Drop using jQuery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am currently working on a project where I have to create a custom calendar sort of application to display and manage appointments easily.

I need to be able to drag and reschedule appointments appropriately. jQuery-ui is pretty neat and I am able to achieve almost everything except that I require that no appointments (divs) may overlap. I am not able to figure out how to achieve this. If someone could guide me into the right direction for this, it would be great.

Thanking you in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: You may want to split this into 2 questions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have changed the question accordingly.

Comment: I have solved my own problem by doing a server side validation using ajax :D, apart from that I also had to hack jquery-ui to be able to get the originalPosition of the draggable to be able to reposition it back to it in case it is infact a collision.
I will be writing a blog entry soon on the same and others who may be facing the same issue know.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plug-in seems to handle collisions during drags: [Collidable Draggables](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/collidable).

Alternatively, you could check for collisions when the drag ends, and cancel the drag.  To give you an idea, someone has done this for resizing [here](http://www.nabble.com/Is-it-possible-to-programmatically-cancel-a-resize--td23470281s27240.html#a23744663).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your valuable help, I am now experimenting with the same. Hope to get it the way I want.

Comment: Unfortunately the plugin you suggestion does not function as advertised.